# Failed to connect to iphone XR in appium studio

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-ios

got error of  "Failed to connect to XCAutomation"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting an error of Failed to connect to XCAutomation due to I have the latest software version iOS 14.3 in the mobile (iPhone XR) & I am using the old version of Appium Studio 20.6.7047. I have upgraded to the latest software and the problem resolved.

Reference Link: https://appium.experitest.com/t/failed-to-connect-xcautomation-after-upgrading-to-ios-14-1/2130/4

Download links for appium Studio:

For Mac: https://go.experitest.com/appium-studio-download-mac-thank-you-page

For Windows: https://go.experitest.com/appium-studio-for-windows